# gitlab pull request without automatic merge

Tags: gitlab

My team has been using Crucible for our code reviews, but we've moved our git repository to Gitlab and would like to take advantage of its code review module, however we've run into a problem.

Our process is that the engineer who wrote the code creates the code review, sends it to whoever should review it, and then when the review is complete (and passes), the engineer who wrote it is responsible for merging their branch wherever it should be.

We're trying to use Gitlab's pull request, but we don't want Git lab to automatically merge if the review is accepted.  Is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up hacking the code a little and commenting out the contents of the div with the accept merge request button.